# Calling a function with an encrypt name in VbScript

Tags: vbscript, cryptography

I want to call a function with an encrypt name,
for example the function [Replace(String,"1","0")] I want to call this function without using its name(this is for a school project).
Thank you.

Comment: You should post what did you tried as code until now ! take a look at this ==> http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [GetRef()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekabbe10%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to get a reference to a user-defined Sub or Function and call it indirectly via that 'pointer':

```
Option Explicit

Function f()
  f = "F"
End Function

Dim g : Set g = GetRef("f")
WScript.Echo g()
```

output:

```
cscript 35381024.vbs
F
```

But GetRef does not apply to native Subs/Functions like Replace. So you would need an additional wrapper function.

Comment: Thank you for help that's what I was searching

Comment: I downvoted by mistake, the answer is correct. Can't change my vote until the answer is edited ):